# Why isn't Nuxt transpiling vendors.app.js?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I'm having some trouble with Nuxt/Webpack transipiling the code that gets bundled in `vendors.app.js`. Arrow functions and `let/const` are still being shipped to the browser in this file if they're present in the original lib in `node_modules`. This is an issue because we need to support IE11.

I've searched everywhere and haven't found a solution. I've tried:

1) https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/#transpile

2) https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/3485

3) Opting out of `@nuxt/babel-preset-app` and trying my own babel preset/plugin overrides in `nuxt.config.js`

What else can I try?

Comment: out of sheer "want-to-know", why do you need to support IE11?

Comment: Your first option is exactly what you look for

Comment: Good job adding the javascript tag to your post. Many newer users are just putting the library they use, not the language itself. Keep that up my man.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is that webpack does nothing transpiling about `optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups`.
So make sure your dependencies is exported by es5.

[nuxt splitChunks config](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/ff6e6ef6773d8fd732f16de5dfc12adb4d06dbde/packages/webpack/src/config/client.js#L56)